# Issue with the PHP mbstring() function?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, performance, swatches

I'm getting the following error message when I select some category in the main manu:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in home/magento19.test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Data.php on line 82
```

The error message got back after upgrade from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 and PHP 5.4 to 5.5, but the error message had appeared already some weeks ago and dissappeared after I setted the `max_execution_time` directive at 60 seconds in the `php.ini` config file.

The line in question is inside the method `normalizeKey` and call to `mb_strtolower` and `trim`:

```
public static function normalizeKey($key) {
    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
        return trim(mb_strtolower($key, 'UTF-8'));
    }
    return trim(strtolower($key));
}
```

The code to display thumbs swatches in the result searches was deleted, but I guess there's must be some around related.

`mbstring` PHP module was installed yesterday (to solve an obvious issue with email templating), so it shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: The problem is not `mb_strtolower` itself but that this is called too often. It is a known bug in the swatches module. Please have a look at this question, which addresses the same issue: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55709/enterprise-1-14-1-swatches-causing-35-sec-plus-load-time-on-category-pages

Comment: I guess I'll have to install AOE Profiler to track and find the cause of this issue. Thanks for the link.

Comment: After a month away of this issue I decided to follow the instructions of Андрей М. (instead of profiling the webpage with the issue) and it solved the problem. BTW, I really ignore why it was affecting only one category page instead of all of them, there's nothing special in the product's name in that category.