# Magento 1.9.2.2 Multiple CPU processes continue in maintenance mode

Tags: magento-1.9, redis, maintenance

I have **VPS 8cpu, 16gb ram. php-fpm+Redis+po full page cache**

Sometimes **multiple php** processes appearing and not finishing. Eating cpu each one of them. Almost %100 cpu usage. Memory is below %10

I activated maintanance mode. maintenance.flag is active. Web site is not online.

I restarted php-fpm

Processes stopped, after couple of minutes started again and still continue.

When I activate magento Server is not stucked, I can reach whm and ssh but magento is sooo slow.

How can I find what is working? Or which script is working?

Comment: use `strace -p xxxxxx` or `lsof -p xxxxx`  where xxxxx is php-fpm pid number, you will see whats going on there

Comment: @MagenX thank you. I can see details of products via lsof. What about exact magento process? I am reading about magento profiler but when I saw on forums I dont like it. Which script is best for checking magento errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found a solution.

1- Configurable swatches was problem. There was loop as a core problem of magento.

I fixed as below. Speed x 5

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55709/enterprise-1-14-1-swatches-causing-35-sec-plus-load-time-on-category-pages

I changed below file

/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php

2- Second problem was featured and New products fall on homepage.
I was choosen all products for showing homepage. Script was trying to work for all products per visitor. That was the reason of Apache stucks.